# Unable to load intellij module when using mvn idea:idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using: IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3 (Community edition) and Maven 3.0.4.

The project contains several modules, one of them creates a war-file.
When I use "mvn idea:idea" IntelliJ is unable to load this module for some reason.
The error message is:
"10:40:04 AM Error Loading Project: Cannot load module"

I can fix the problem by manually importing existing module, but this is a very annoying problem. Does anyone know why this happens, could it be a maven or intellij problem? Is it something I can do to fix it?

Comment: Just open the project by pointing to the `pom.xml` file. Skip the `maven-idea-plugin`, it is obsolete...

Comment: Alright, thanks. Too bad if the plugin is obsolete though

Comment: Why is it bad that the plugin is obsolete? The guys at Jetbrains are probably as clever as the ones who ever developed the `maven-idea-plugin`.

Comment: Its no big issue, I love the jetbrains products. Just need to use the IDE feature instead of directly using maven in this case. This is good to know anyway, since I heavily used eclipse:eclipse previously.

Comment: I don't think you should use the `maven-eclipse-plugin` either. It is also obsolete. There is the [`m2e`](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin to use directly from Eclipse instead.

Comment: I have never had issues with eclipse:eclipse, but with m2e however... but, this is off topic.

Comment: Added an answer to summarize what has been written here so you can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just open the project by pointing to the `pom.xml` file. Skip the `maven-idea-plugin`, it is obsolete.

The [`maven-idea-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/) has not been active since 2008.

Answer (score 5):

`mvn idea:idea` is obsolete and should not be used, it's known to cause problems. Just open `pom.xml` directly from IDEA and it will import the Maven project.

To import with more options create a new project from the external Maven model.

Answer (score 0):

`mvn idea:idea` is no longer used. The official [page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/usage.html) for the plugins usage states  `Apache Maven IDEA Plugin (RETIRED)`.

You can directly do `File -> Import project` and select `pom.xml` file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on Mac (i.e. "Error Loading Project: Cannot load module") too. This is how mine was fixed.

1. Tap with two finger on the Trackpad (kind of right click in away) on pom.xml file.
2. Go down in the menu to "Maven" and then select "Reimport".

That made it work for me, hope this helps you too :)

[image]