# Maven / IDEA setting the Resource patterns

Tags: maven, groovy, intellij-idea

My project is using Maven to compile both Java and Groovy classes.
My project compiles and builds just fine using maven but I would like IDEA (IntelliJ) to build it correctly as well. I use maven to generate the IDEA project file with the following command:

```
mvn idea:idea
```

I noticed it doesn't build the groovy files, only the java files.

I found out the issue was that by default IDEA was considering all the files not having a .java extension as resources.

When I generate the project file with the maven IDEA plugin I get the following in the ipr file

```
<component name="CompilerConfiguration">
<option name="DEFAULT_COMPILER" value="Javac" />
<resourceExtensions />
<wildcardResourcePatterns>
  <entry name="!?*.java" />
</wildcardResourcePatterns>
...
```

I have to modify it this way in order to have my groovy files compiling (and few others kind of files):

```
<component name="CompilerConfiguration">
<option name="DEFAULT_COMPILER" value="Javac" />
<resourceExtensions />
<wildcardResourcePatterns>
  <entry name="!?*.java" />
  <entry name="!?*.groovy" />
  <entry name="!?*.scala" />
  <entry name="!?*.flex" />
</wildcardResourcePatterns>
...
```

*Note: this information can be found/edited as well in IDEA -> Settings -> Compiler -> Resource patterns*

I can generate it correctly using the following command:

```
mvn idea:idea -DwildcardResourcePatterns="!?*.java;!?*.groovy;"
```

Does anyone know how to configure this in the pom.xml?

Comment: Never ever use `mvn idea:idea`, it's outdated, unsupported, generates broken projects. Always open pom files directly and IDEA will generate/import the project.

Comment: Works pretty well for me but thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This need to be added in the pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
       <wildcardResourcePatterns>!?*.java;!?*.groovy;</wildcardResourcePatterns>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: You really should follow @CrazyCoder's advice to never use the `maven-idea-plugin`, it is obsolete. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898360/unable-to-load-intellij-module-when-using-mvn-ideaidea/11903127#11903127

Comment: Thank you, I will. I was just saying it was working for me :)