# Package name does not correspond to the file path

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am new to maven and trying to run simple spring demo. I am using Intellij IDEA as my IDE. I am following tutorial provided [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/quick-start-maven-spring-example/).

So i ran

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=SpringDemo -DartifactId=SpringExamples 
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

and then did

```
mvn idea:idea
```

It generated all .ipr,.iws etc file. Then I simply did open from IDEA and selected the .ipr file. It detected it as IDEA project and opened it but it gives me following error

```
Package name 'cospring' does not correspond to the file path 'cospring-demo'
```

App class is

```
package cospring-demo;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

What is the issue? Any work around?

Comment: I think `cospring-demo` is not a valid package name (contains hyphen) try using `cospring` in your class `App`.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `mvn idea:idea`. It is obsolete: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11903127/1350762.

Answer (score 1):

This is good explanation

> Maven *groupIds* prefer dashes ("`-`"), but the Java compiler forbids dashes in package names. Yet the archetype plugin simply spits out what the user gave as the *groupId*. [ARCHETYPE-216](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-216)

Simply avoid using `-` in `groupId` generated from archetype.

> If the domain name contains a hyphen, or any other special character not allowed in an identifier (§3.8), convert it into an underscore. [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1)

- [Naming a Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)
- [What is the convention for word separator in Java package names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179216/what-is-the-convention-for-word-separator-in-java-package-names)