# Multiple IntelliJ/Maven modules with 'same' name?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

As a newcomer to Java/Maven/IntelliJ from .NET world the project structure below (nested modules with 'local' `core` submodules created through IDE, no handcrafted `pom`'s) makes perfect sense to me. How come IntelliJ doesn't like multiple `core`'s after reopening the project? Is it bad project/folder structure? Can I get around it without unnecessarily prefixing each `core` with redundant `foo-bar-` and `foo-baz-` qualifiers and polluting Project window (`artifactId`'s have them already for builds)?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP8Ch.png

[image]

Comment: As far as i know IntelliJ has some kind of configuration (template?) to enhance the name of the modules with the groupId (Eclipse has exact this)...

Comment: Just to into Project Settings -> Modules and rename 'core' to 'foo-bar-core'. It wont affect your build, purely cosmetic.

Answer (score -2):

Your project structure is fine. The issue I feel is with the IDE, I had seen this with Eclipse too.

The IDE should name the project with regards tot he artifactId in the pom.xml file, this can of course be overridden, have you tried running mvn idea:idea?

Comment: Don't encourage the use of `mvn idea:idea`. It has been retired and not updated since 2008. IntelliJ has built-in functionality to support Maven. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11903127/1350762