# Stop IntelliJ polluting Project tool window with module names?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

On the back of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29495060/384478) question, is there a way in IntelliJ to disable displaying the full `.iml` module name **[in bold and in square brackets]** next to folder name when it is simply a fully qualified version of it? It is unnecessarily noisy on a big project...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE5nz.png

[image]

Comment: The way we achieved a "proper" way to do that was to always have a unique artifactId (in your case, it would be for instance _foo.bar.baz.amet_, and having the directory name being the same as the artifactId.

Comment: @Tome yes, it's starting to look like it's the only way, but I feel like it almost defeats the purpose of having them nested and nice looking. artifactId is fully qualified anyway, IntelliJ doesn't seem to take it into account, only .iml and folder names.

Comment: Module name (which impacts the .iml, and results in the bold name), IIRC, is by default the same as the artifactId, and if you have fully qualified artifactId, these should be unique and not causing problems. Of course without having the directory name the same as the artifactId, you will have this pollution, as I couldn't see any way to disable one of the names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a related feature request open in IntelliJ IDEA issue tracker:

- [IDEA-82965 Clean module names](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82965)

Feel free to [vote/comment](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23368682).

Comment: Thanks. Is it something that can be done by a plugin? Does IntelilJ SDK have a hook into Project tool window?

Answer (score 2):

As a newcomer to both IntelliJ and Maven, I also found the module names to be noisy.  Perhaps I'll need them later, but for now I needed to be able to focus on the file directory structure and just needed them gone.  Switching from "Project" to "Project Files" did the trick.  The Project Files view has an option in its Options Menu to Show Modules that I was able to disable.  Maven module information is no longer visible.  It might not be the perfect long term solution, as I don't fully understand the difference in the views yet, but it did reduce the as-yet-unnecessary information I was being bombarded with.

(Thanks to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126014 for pointing this out while working on a similar issue.)