# How to remove bold style for project name in Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

I don not know when project names turn bold, how to set to normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason: artifact Id should different from directory name.

[image]

Comment: And now you have the square bracket problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509614/stop-intellij-polluting-project-tool-window-with-module-names

Answer (score 3):

The bold names denote your project modules, which is why they also have that blue square on the folder icon.

There does not seem to currently be a way to alter the text-style of items in the project structure tree. Though you can try opening an issue on [JetBrains' tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues) for this.

Comment: Hi @phaze0, what do you mean by project modules?