# Use Maven2, mvn idea:idea, but report NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

my environment is Mac 10.10.4, jdk7, maven2.
When i use mvn idea:idea to make the project, but i met the error.

```
[INFO] [idea:idea {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] null
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ResolutionNode.addDependencies(ResolutionNode.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.collect(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:304)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:285)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.idea.IdeaModuleMojo.getArtifacts(IdeaModuleMojo.java:705)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.idea.IdeaModuleMojo.rewriteDependencies(IdeaModuleMojo.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.idea.IdeaModuleMojo.rewriteModule(IdeaModuleMojo.java:423)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.idea.IdeaMojo.rewriteModule(IdeaMojo.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.idea.IdeaMojo.execute(IdeaMojo.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 25 18:19:30 CST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 87M/1323M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I felt may be the idea plugin error, try many ways, but it can't resolve, anyone met this problem either?

Comment: Why would you use this plugin? [It is retired](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/index.html), probably because IntelliJ has excellent Maven-support out of the box.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't bother with the idea:idea plugin.  Just use intellij's import project feature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got it. I used to the mvn eclipse:eclipse command, but idea can import the project automatic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to load intellij module when using mvn idea:idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898360/unable-to-load-intellij-module-when-using-mvn-ideaidea)

Comment: Stop using [Maven 2 cause it's End of Life](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html).